# How to delete $PATH variable?

Tags: bash, macos, path

everytime I start my terminal I get this output, I am trying to delete the `$PATH` variable but without success...

```
Last login: Wed Sep 21 17:19:19 on ttys001
-bash: /Users/Miguel/Applications/adb/adb_Mac: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you show us how you do that, and the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: You really do not want to delete your `PATH` variable. Your shell relies on it having *some* sensible value.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is probably more relevant; terminal emulators in OS X tend to start login shells by default, and the `Last login:` message supports that happening here.

Comment: Hi guys, I solved the problem. The _.bash_profile_ file was wrong. Thank you @chepner